# Converting Android Bitmap to LibGdx's Texture

Tags: android, libgdx

i am trying to convert bitmap into a libGDX Texture by converting:

1. Android `Bitmap` to `byte[]`
2. `byte[]` to libGDX [`Pixmap`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.html)
3. libGDX `Pixmap` to libGDX `Texture`

The problem I am facing is that the bitmap which is converted to texture is drawing the sprite sheet from texture packer that is in assets folder

```
public void onByteArrayOfCroppedImageReciever(byte[] bytes) {
    try {
        pmap=new Pixmap(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        tex=new Texture(pmap);
        face=new Sprite(tex);
        // game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game, batcher, face));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Gdx.app.log("KS", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Its very odd to see the wrong content in the Pixmap.  Are you sure you're drawing the Pixmap you expect?  Try creating a new Pixmap() with known content (e.g., use "drawCircle") and make sure you see the pixmap you display.  Also, the Pixmap constructor you're currently using expects JPG/PNG/BMP encoded bytes.  How did you get the bytes out of the Android Bitmap?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

hmm another possibility is that you've got a threading issue. I've noticed this kind of problem when loading my own unmanaged textures on the UI thread while libgdx is doing its thing loading textures concurrently on the render thread.
If this is the problem the simple solution is to synchronize the creation of the texture with the render thread using Gdx.app.postRunnable. i.e.:

```
public void onByteArrayOfCroppedImageReciever(byte[] bytes) {
    try {
        pmap=new Pixmap(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {            
                tex=new Texture(pmap);
                face=new Sprite(tex);
            }
        });
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Gdx.app.log("KS", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This question and answer saved my life!

Comment: @P_Dog I'm facing problem with thread. Can you help with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660894/send-data-out-of-gdx-app-postrunnable-thread

Comment: What is the byte array? Is it a compressed image (PNG/JPG/WEBP) ? or is it the Bitmap itself somehow? Please explain

Answer (score 21):

If the goal is to convert an Android Bitmap to a libgdx Texture, you don't need to use Pixmap at all. You can do it directly with the help of simple OpenGL and Android GLUtils. Try the followings; it is 100x faster than your solution. I assume that you are not in the rendering thread (you should not most likely). If you are, you don't need to call postRunnable().

```
       Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          Texture tex = new Texture(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Format.RGBA8888);
          GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex.getTextureObjectHandle());
          GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
          GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
          bitmap.recycle();
          // now you have the texture to do whatever you want
        }
      });
```

Comment: thanks a lot bro will try that for sure in future is i need it

THanks

Comment: Android Bitmap stores alpha premultiplied pixels. You can use batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); to draw the texture then to compensate for this

Comment: This is fantastic. So much faster than using Pixmaps. I am wondering if it's possible to create the Texture with width/height flipped, then bind the bitmap rotated 90/270 degrees? This is because many images from the gallery are orientated incorrectly since rotation is stored in the Exif data. I'm looking for a quick solution to rotate them without the typical expensive Matrix transform.

Comment: This helped handling WEBP files, which for some reason I've failed to load. How come it's still not supported on libGdx?

Answer (score 1):

you have to code on  a new thread because pixmap class takes time for byte conversion and sometimes returns a temporary pixmap in case the process hasnt finished so its better to run on a seperate thread and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Are you committed to that operational pipeline?  Here's an alternate way to do the conversion you asked for:

1. Implement com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData to take an android.graphics.Bitmap in    the constructor.
2. In prepare(), allocate and fill an IntBuffer using Bitmap.getPixels.
3. Use bitmath to swap the data in the buffer from ARGB to RGBA: `(arr[i] << 8) | (arr[i]>>24)`
4. In getType() return TextureData.TextureDataType.Compressed
5. In consumeCompressedData() call glTexImage2D to feed the data into the (prebound) texture.

Your pipeline above includes several copies and recompressions of pixel data; this pipeline allows you to feed your Bitmap data straight into the texture with only one copy (necessary for the byte format conversion anyway).  Would that work for you?

Comment: Will try it for sure and will let u know if it solves my purpose doing it this way