# Libgdx update texture at runtime

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I need to update a texture at runtime, my code is:

```
    public void updateTexture(Bitmap bmp) {
        mTexture = new Texture( ImageHelper.bitmapToPixmap( bmp ) );
    }
```

But it is not working. Can somebody help me?
Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
    public void render(PerspectiveCamera camera) {

        mTexture.bind();
        mShaderProgram.begin();

            mShaderProgram.setUniformMatrix("u_worldView", camera.combined );
            mShaderProgram.setUniformi("u_texture", 0);
                mMesh.render(mShaderProgram, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);

        mShaderProgram.end();
    }
```

**NEW PROBLEME**

I get the first old texture on all my objects.

Comment: What does not working mean specifically?  Does the old texture not go away?  Do you see a blank?  Do you store the `mTexture` in any of your other objects?

Comment: Wat P.T. said makes sense also I think your mTexture is being disposed twice .... check tht out nd see if other objects are by anychance referring to mTexture thus makin it unable to update...

Comment: I can see the old texture. Not the new. The texture is flashing once and thats all. Am I have to call .dispose(); or not? I have an arraylist with a custom class that holds the mTexture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK finally I found the probleme here:

[Converting Android Bitmap to LibGdx's Texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930463/converting-android-bitmap-to-libgdxs-texture)

**working code:**

```
public void updateTexture(final Bitmap bmp) {

     Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {            
                mTexture    = new Texture( mImageHelper.bitmapToPixmap( bmp ) );
                mSprite.setTextureRegion(new TextureRegion(mTexture));
            }
     });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are calling

```
mTexture.disose();
```

that frees the object, and then you try to assign another object to it. This will never work.
What you can do, instead is:

```
public void updateTexture(Bitmap bmp) {
    mTexture = new Texture( ImageHelper.bitmapToPixmap( bmp ) );
}
```

and that should sort it out. Although this is really never recommended to do, as it creates another object in the same instance, but whatever, right?