# Return/Pass ImageView file

Tags: android, interface, libgdx

I generate a ImageView in my AndroidLauncher and need to use it in one of my screen classes, so I created an interface. How can I pass that image and use it in my screen class? Do I need to make it into a Bitmap first?

What I got right now is:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImage);
            imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
```

and my interface:

```
public interface purchInterface{
public void getSelectedImage();
}
```

and in AndroidLauncher:

```
@Override
public void getSelectedImage() {
    imageView.getDrawable();
}
```

Im in deep water here. Note that I need to be able to draw this Image in my screen class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the image encoded in some format from `getSelectedImage` method. Otherwise your implementation is retrieving the drawable and dropping it immediately.

You should refer to [Converting Android Bitmap to LibGdx's Texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930463/converting-android-bitmap-to-libgdxs-texture)

---

So your interface could be

```
public interface purchInterface {
    public byte[] getSelectedImage();
}
```

And implementation could be

```
@Override
public byte[] getSelectedImage() {
    // Convert image into bitmap, encode in a byte array.
}
```

You can call the interface's method and decode the byte array using method described in above question.

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I recieve this method from override in my screen class: public byte[] getSelectedImage(){return new byte[0];} how can I use this to draw the content of the byte?

Comment: The code in the question I mentioned above can directly be used to create a `Texture` from an array ob bytes.

Comment: Yes but how do I use getSelectedImage() when it´s overrided to my screen class and actually draw it? I can´t really draw getSelectedImage() as somehow right?

Answer (score 0):

Use singleton class and store image in it using setter() and later u can use getter ().

Or you convert the image to string using base64 encoding and save it shared preferences or file or database or external storage or pass as intent data to next activity and then decode it to bitmap