# convert bitmap to texture or Image libgdx

Tags: android, bitmap, libgdx

I want to pass a Bitmap from android module to core module in libgdx, but there is no such class in libgdx. How should i do that?

I can hold my data in byte[]. How can i create Image or Texture from byte[]?

Correct answer was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930463/converting-android-bitmap-to-libgdxs-texture)

Comment: Perhaps [these posts](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1175#p6948) on the libGDX forums will help.  It's the best I could find.

Comment: Actually, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930463/converting-android-bitmap-to-libgdxs-texture) seems to have a [good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21319295/1540030).

Comment: @Malkierian thanks. it worked

Comment: haha my question helping others. stack rocks