# Create libgdx Sprite using bitmap image in java file

Tags: java, android, bitmap, libgdx

I'm modifying an already written code in Android. Here a libgdx Sprite is being created like this using an image from assets:

```
Sprite sp = new Sprite(assets.get("images/image.png", Texture.class));
```

I've picked an image from gallery(which is in bitmap) and want to create its sprite. I couldn't save this image in assets as its not possible. Can anyone suggest some solution?

Here is the code which I'm using to retrieve image form gallery and save as bitmap.

```
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(selectedImageUri, projection, null,null,
    null);

    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String selectedImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);

    Bitmap bm; // To Save image as Bitmap
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);

    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 200;
    int scale = 1;
    while (options.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
    && options.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
    scale *= 2;
    options.inSampleSize = scale;
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath, options);
```

Comment: What's the class od an image object? show us a code od retrieving the image

Comment: I've added the code @m.antkowicz

Comment: thx - also add pls these two imports where you are importing Bitmap and BitmapFactory classes

Comment: Where I'm retrieving image , it's a android activity class but where I want to use , it's libgdx java class. I've a common class between them where I'm storing this bitmap image.

Comment: look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930463/converting-android-bitmap-to-libgdxs-texture - it should help your problem

Comment: I suggest saving a copy of the image into Local storage. Something like this: `Gdx.input.absolute(selectedImageUri.getPath()).copyTo(Gdx.input.local("imageCopy.png");`. And then load the image you copied: `texture = new Texture(Gdx.input.local("imageCopy.png"));` so the texture will be *managed*, meaning it is automatically reloaded when necessary when the app resumes from suspend.

Comment: @Tenfour04 above code was giving error of absolute function not available. So I used this one `Gdx.files.absolute(selectedImageUri.getPath()).copyTo(Gdx.files.local("imageCop‌​y.png"));` but it's giving me runtime error now **Failed to write file**

Comment: Yeah I meant to write files. Look at the error messages and fix them. You might have to do some parsing of the absolute path. I haven't tested it.

Comment: @m.antkowicz I used that thread to convert bitmap to texture , set texture to a sprite and return that sprite but I'm unable to send data out of thread. Can you please help with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32660894/send-data-out-of-gdx-app-postrunnable-thread

Comment: is it not possible to place the code in some render function? For me it seems to be not very good to make it asynchronous here - are you afraid that creating the sprite will take much time? In that case - is this bitmap is such big?

Comment: render function? I couldn't get it

Comment: I mean main thread - the main loop of the application - to be more clear jest create sprite instead od starting thread that will create it