# How to convert a LibGdx group actor into Android bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, libgdx

Has any way to convert from LibGdx Group in to Android bitmap?
Please help me this issue! Thank you!

Comment: Look at the [solutions in the comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930463/converting-android-bitmap-to-libgdxs-texture)

Comment: You could try to create a screenshot with all other actors set to invisible. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Take-a-Screenshot The pixmap you get from this method can be turned into a texture. Since I don't use native android classes I can't provide a full answer, but I guess this should help.