# libGDX: How can I tell core game getIconImageUri() and use it as Image actor into my game

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-services

I created `IGoogleServices` interface on core project:

```
public interface IGoogleServices {    
    .....
    public String getPlayerName();
}
```

Then I put the following code inside the implementaion method in `MainActivity` on android project:

```
private String name;
@Override
public String getPlayerName() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            name = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(_gameHelper.getApiClient()).getDisplayName();
        }
    });
    return name;
}
```

This is simple way to tell `MyGame` the player name as a `String`:

```
lblPlayerName = new Label("" + googleServices.getPlayerName(), style);
stage.addActor(lblPlayerName);
```

**BUT** I can't do it in the image case.

In the same previous `String` case, I tried to do it in the image case:

```
private Uri imgUri;
@Override
public void requestImgProfile() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            imgUri = Games.Players.getCurrentPlayer(_gameHelper.getApiClient()).getIconImageUri();
            ImageManager manager = ImageManager.create(MainActivity.this);
            manager.loadImage(new ImageManager.OnImageLoadedListener() {
                public void onImageLoaded(Uri arg0, Drawable drawable, boolean arg2) {
                        try {
                            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
                            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);;
                            out = openFileOutput(imgUri + ".png", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
                            out.flush();
                            out.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, imgUri);
            };
        });
    }
```

My `imgUri` is:

```
content://com.google.android.gms.games.background/images/26s5523b/2633
```

What is the class type (like `String`) which I can tell `MyGame` it and libGDX libraries can treat with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an Image URI, you can get a Bitmap via:

```
Uri imgUri;
Bitmap bitmap = null;
try {
    InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imgUri);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
}
```

This works whether it is a `file://` URI or `content://` URI.

Then use solutions such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21319295/1676363) to convert the Bitmap into something usable by libGDX.

Comment: Nice, but how can I tell `MyGame` which libGDX libraries can not treat with `Bitmap` (android)??

Comment: @iOleX - added a link to a solution which converts Bitmaps into something readable by libGDX

Comment: YA THAT IS IT. Thanx A Lot @ianhanniballake For your adding that answer :* :) It's work Coool